# TinyMCE custom theme jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, themes

This is an example for tiny mce with a custom jquery ui theme:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/IDbaab

and this is an example for tiny mce with all functions enabled:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/baaaab

How can I comebine these 2?

Writing everything like this

```
'<input type="checkbox" id="bold" data-mce-command="bold" /><label for="bold">B</label>' +
'<input type="checkbox" id="italic" data-mce-command="italic" /><label for="italic">I</label>' +
```

would really stupid, is there a better and easy solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using ckeditor now, much better
http://ckeditor.com/
Also, the new tiny editor has an improved theme

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work but couldn't you generate that html from the "theme_advanced_buttons" option?

```
var html = '';
$.each(theme_advanced_buttons.split(',|,'), function(){
   $.each(theme_advanced_buttons.split(','), function(id, value){
      html += '<input type="checkbox" id="'+value+'" data-mce-command="'+value+'" /><label for="'+value+'">'+value+'</label>';
   });
   html += 'separator_html';
});
```

You would probably need another array to define the displayed text (B, I etc)

Comment: thanks but this is not working, you can try it yourself in the fiddle

Comment: it wasn't meant as a ready to use solution. you just had to adjust it a little.
this version http://fiddle.tinymce.com/IDbaab/3 works, but you'll have to replace the seperator_html, define an array with the button texts and generate the buttons from theme_advanced_buttons2 - 4.

Comment: this works to just get some buttons, but I also need the correct icons etc.. I'll find another editor

Comment: Or you could look through the code to see how it's done in other themes.

Answer (score 0):

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/IDbaab/2

here, I have added an Underline Button

'U' +

above, checkbox is type of button, 
data-mce-command attribute defines which command it will run
and label for it

you should do this for all commands...

Comment: thanks, but adding a line for every command is just too silly, is the theming part just bad implemented?

Comment: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/IDbaab/4

this can give you an idea
however input types and labels and values changes button to button...
I think you should write it one by one.

Comment: ok thanks for the help, but writing it one by one is just ridiculous, I'll find another editor